# Filling an array with contents

Tags: arrays, ruby

Write a function that produces an array with the numbers 0 to N-1 in it.

I wrote:

```
def arr(n)
   Array.new(n) { |n| n+=1 }
end
```

It gives me the following result

Test Results:
Fixed tests
should pass fixed tests
Expected: [0, 1, 2, 3], instead got: [1, 2, 3, 4]

How do I change it to include "0"?

Comment: `Array.new(n) { |n| n }` is all you need. The `n` block argument gets incremented by `Array.new`, you just have to return it from the block. You might want to write `Array.new(n) { |i| i }` (i.e. use another argument name) or `Array.new(n, &:itself)`

Answer (score 1):

What about creating an array from a Range object

```
def arr(n)
  (0...n).to_a
end
```

Or if you want to solve it using `Array.new`, you can go like this:

```
def arr(n)
  Array.new(n) { |n| n }
end
```

(just don't add `1` to `n` inside a block)

Comment: It doesn't pass all the tests. I tried to implement .select.to_a 
def arr(n)
  (0..n).select.to_a
end
It included 0 but takes more integers than necessary, it gives the following Expected: [0, 1, 2, 3], instead got: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Why did you choose to subtract 1 on the range solution, rather than using `0…n` (3 dots)?

Comment: Forgot about this syntax, thanx for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

At this point I see four distinct solutions proposed, all of which produce the desired array. So if they're all correct, is one of them preferable? I decided to benchmark:

```ruby
# gem install benchmark-ips first!
require 'benchmark/ips'

def range_to_a(n)
  (0...n).to_a
end

def new_w_block(n)
  Array.new(n) { |n| n }
end

def new_w_itself(n)
  Array.new(n, &:itself)
end

def splat_range(n)
  [*0...n]
end

N = (ARGV.shift || 100).to_i

Benchmark.ips do |bmrk|
  bmrk.report('range_to_a') do
    range_to_a(N)
  end
  bmrk.report('new_w_block') do
    new_w_block(N)
  end
  bmrk.report('new_w_itself') do
    new_w_itself(N)
  end
  bmrk.report('splat_range') do
    splat_range(N)
  end
  bmrk.compare!
end
```

The results on an M1 MacBook Pro using `ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin21]` are:

```text
Warming up --------------------------------------
          range_to_a    65.027k i/100ms
         new_w_block    35.147k i/100ms
        new_w_itself    32.523k i/100ms
         splat_range    61.507k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
          range_to_a    650.174k (± 0.8%) i/s -      3.251M in   5.001095s
         new_w_block    351.006k (± 0.7%) i/s -      1.757M in   5.006876s
        new_w_itself    328.290k (± 1.3%) i/s -      1.659M in   5.053325s
         splat_range    619.419k (± 1.1%) i/s -      3.137M in   5.064811s

Comparison:
          range_to_a:   650174.3 i/s
         splat_range:   619419.4 i/s - 1.05x  (± 0.00) slower
         new_w_block:   351005.7 i/s - 1.85x  (± 0.00) slower
        new_w_itself:   328289.6 i/s - 1.98x  (± 0.00) slower
```

Both `range` based solutions beat both `new` based solutions by substantial margins, with `(0...n).to_a` being the winner and `Array.new(n, &:itself)` as the loser.

With ruby 2.6.8p205 (the ruby that ships with MacOS), the `new` solutions gained ground but still trailed significantly. Relative rankings did not change:

```text
Warming up --------------------------------------
          range_to_a    59.870k i/100ms
         new_w_block    38.292k i/100ms
        new_w_itself    35.207k i/100ms
         splat_range    56.641k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
          range_to_a    599.798k (± 1.0%) i/s -      3.053M in   5.091209s
         new_w_block    376.282k (± 1.9%) i/s -      1.915M in   5.090098s
        new_w_itself    350.326k (± 1.1%) i/s -      1.760M in   5.025558s
         splat_range    570.727k (± 1.7%) i/s -      2.889M in   5.062856s

Comparison:
          range_to_a:   599797.6 i/s
         splat_range:   570727.4 i/s - 1.05x  (± 0.00) slower
         new_w_block:   376281.7 i/s - 1.59x  (± 0.00) slower
        new_w_itself:   350326.1 i/s - 1.71x  (± 0.00) slower
```

All hail `(0...n).to_a`, the current ruler!

Comment: Good research. I think it's because new variable is initialized every time, when block is used (both `new` use blocks). And loser need more time to "convert" symbol to proc and pass it to block

Answer (score 0):

You can use splat operator and range with `...` that excludes the end of the range

```
def arr(n)
  [*0...n]
end
```

```
arr(4)
# => [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieved by using

for 0 to n-1

```
def arr(n)
   arr = (0...n).to_a
end
```

for 0 to n

```
def arr(n)
   arr = (0..n).to_a
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is (arguably the most) idiomatic one-liner:

```
n = 5 # for example
Array.new(n, &:itself)
```

`&:itself` is [equivalent](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-itself) of the block `{ |x| x }`, and `Array.new` as said in [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new) accepts block which essentially maps numbers from `0` to `n-1` (where `n` is the first argument to `.new`) to the result of the block (which receives each number as the argument).